# Possible bug or at least usability issue with login process involving OpenID

Tags: bug, login, openid, usability, stack-exchange-openid

I visited **ServerFault** earlier and needed to login so I could post a comment; so I went to the login page, couldn't remember my login details, and didn't want to reset them as I didn't really need to as I knew I had my login details stored in *1Password* for the *StackOverflow* domain.

I couldn't be bothered to go in and get my details from 1Password and I thought I knew my OpenID username, which I have logged into StackExchange with before, so I clicked the *More login options* link and then it gave me the dropdown with additional options as per:

[image]

I entered my username and clicked the *Log In* button; but got an error message saying:

> No OpenID endpoint found.

So I figure there is a problem with the `OpenID` login process or I entered the wrong username, so I click the `back` button in my *browser* and then dig out my login credentials from 1Password that I have stored for StackOverflow so I can login with those instead.

When I go back to the page, I am presented with this page (note the additional login options are now collapsed):

[image]

I put in the login details and click the *Log In* button, however, once again I am presented with the same `OpenID` error message of:

> No OpenID endpoint found.

Scratched my head for a few seconds there wondering why I was still getting that error when I was trying to login normally now; then I expanded the additional login options section again, noticed my *username* was still entered into the `OpenID` field and perhaps that was affecting it; once I removed my username I was then able to login successfully.

I guess being that a lot of the **StackExchange** sites are quite technical a lot of users who run into this issue may be able to work it out themselves, but I believe it still is a usability issue and would cause more of a problem for users that come across it that frequent the less technical SE sites.

Comment: Agree we should clear out the fields and/or preserve the expansion state there, but what do you mean by "username" exactly? The freeform OpenID field expects a full URL to your OpenID provider.

Comment: @AdamLear Hmmmm...... I haven't used OpenID in awhile so perhaps I got the terminology wrong, perhaps in the past you had auto prefixed the OpenID field with a URL which we then appended our username to?

Comment: Looks like you used MyOpenID in the past. We did have a dedicated button for them under "more options" that allowed you to ender just the username. MyOpenID shut down a few years back, though, so we took it out and it's unusable even with a full URL.

Comment: @AdamLear Ahh yeah, that was probably it. Cheers!